# Deploying just one dbt model using GitLab Ci/CD to Snowflake

Tags: gitlab, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cicd, dbt

So, I have a dbt project, which contains a number of models in the models folder, divided into mart, intermediate, and staging subfolders. I use GitLab CI/CD to deploy these models to Snowflake.

Now, I'm currently testing these models, and would like to deploy them one by one.

Is it possible to somehow set up GitLab CI/CD (or maybe the dbt project) to just run/deploy one model at a time?

Comment: This will be very slow. Why do you want to do this? If you're looking to test each model right after it's built, check out [`dbt build`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/build) instead of running `dbt run && dbt test`

Answer (score 1):

The `dbt-run` command could be supplemented with `--select` argument.

> [Examples](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax#examples)
>
> **By default, dbt run will execute all of the models in the dependency graph. During development (and deployment), it is useful to specify only a subset of models to run. Use the `--select` flag with dbt run to select a subset of models to run.** Note that the following arguments (`--select`, `--exclude`, and `--selector`) also apply to other dbt tasks, such as test and build.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> $ dbt run --select my_dbt_project_name   # runs all models in your project
> $ dbt run --select my_dbt_model          # runs a specific model
> $ dbt run --select path.to.my.models     # runs all models in a specific directory
> $ dbt run --select my_package.some_model # run a specific model in a specific package
> $ dbt run --select tag:nightly           # run models with the "nightly" tag
> $ dbt run --select path/to/models        # run models contained in path/to/models
> $ dbt run --select path/to/my_model.sql  # run a specific model by its path
> ```
>
> dbt supports a shorthand language for defining subsets of nodes. This language uses the characters `+`, `@`, `*`, and ,.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm looking for a way to set up GitLab CI/CD to run one particular model, by editing the gitlab-ci.yml file, like the deleted answer suggested. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: He's suggesting you replace your existing `dbt run` command with `dbt run -s my_model`. Why doesn't that work for you?